# How to Trigger an event in a Visual Studio Outlook Add-in

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am currently working on a Visual Studio VSTO C# Outlook Add-in project to open a specific type of file from an email when the file is double-clicked, and have it pop up in a new window. How do I handle the double-click function?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what files you're speaking of. In case of attachments, you can use the `BeforeAttachmentRead`, `BeforeAttachmentSave`, and `BeforeAttachmentPreview` events provided by all Outlook item types. The Outlook object model doesn't provide any special event when you double click on the attached files.

Comment: You just need to set a correct handler for the file type on the system. The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that.